# Is there a function to find the object with a maximum value in R

Tags: r

I have two columns "State" and "Population".
I need the name of the State with the highest population.
How to find this in R. The MAX() max(df$columnname) gives only the value without the name of the state. I want the name of the state as well.

Comment: The function [`which.max()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/which.min.html) should do the trick: `df[which.max(df$population), ]`

Answer (score 2):

```
data(iris)

# return row with largest sepal length
iris[which.max(iris$Sepal.Length),]
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4           2 virginica

# return `Species` from row with largest sepal length
iris[which.max(iris$Sepal.Length),"Species"]
#> [1] virginica
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

Created on 2022-01-12 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```